# Error "cannot find symbol class - ch", "cannot find symbol - method nextCh();"

Tags: java

I want to write a program to check if a letter is a vowel or not, but i am getting 2 errors. Please help me out with this.
I am writing this program in bluej as it is required by my school. Where am I wrong?

these are the errors:

- **cannot find symbol class - ch**
- **cannot find symbol method - nextCh();**

```js
import java.util.*;
class prg4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter letter");
    ch l, a, e, i, o, u = sc.nextCh();
    if (l == a)
      System.out.println("vowel");
    else if (l == e)
      System.out.println("vowel");
    else if (l == i)
      System.out.println("vowel");
    else if (l == o)
      System.out.println("vowel");
    else if (l == u)
      System.out.println("vowel");
    else
      System.out.println("not a vowel");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to write Java or Javascript? You've used the jquery tag which is Javascript-related, and included the code as if it's a Javascript snippet, but the code itself looks like Java. It's important to be *really* clear in your head which language you're using - they're very different.

Comment: In terms of the error you're getting, you're trying to use a type called `ch` but there's no such type, and a method called `nextCh` but there's no such method. I suspect you want `char` and `nextChar`, but I would advise you to consider why you thought they were just `ch` to start with, to avoid making similar mistakes in the future.

Comment: It's java. I'm sorry I am in grade 10 and didn't know that jquery is for javascript

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks it helped. I am just starting off with java and will not make similar mistakes in the future.

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` and `u` shouldn't be variables, and even if they were you shouldn't be trying to assign to them the user's input. The user's input should be assigned to `l` and you should compare that to the constant `char` values `'a'`, `'e'`, `'i'`, `'o'` and `'u'`. Also you don't need all those if/else branches.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper It's an if/else project that I had to do.

Comment: @ROXinfo You should have mentioned that in the question then. Always include all requirements in the question, including what you can and can't use. Or in this case, what you must use.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper sure I will definitely take care of that in the future. I am new here, so the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a char as an input you need to use the scanner like this:

```
char x = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

So the characther will be saved in that x variable and u will be able to compare it in the if statements.

Then the if statement would be like:

```
if (x == 'a') {
  System.out.println("It is a vowel.");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, the class is now compiled without errors.

Comment: but can you tell me the difference between single and double quotes in java?

Comment: @ROXinfo Single quotes are used for `char` values. Double quotes are used for `String` values.